# Live-server unable to access parent directory

Tags: npm-live-server

I'm using the live-server package to launch my page, and it seems parent directories cannot be accessed (for example, `'../public/file.txt'`). Placing this file into working directory, live-server will be able to load it.

Is there a way to allow access to parent directories?